# each function inside each function

Tags: jquery

My html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">House, Cat, Dog, Car</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">House, Cat, Car</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">Cat, Dog</div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
$('.wrapper > .objects').each(function() {

    var objects = $(this).text();
    var objectsSplit = objects.split(',');

    // console.log(objectsSplit);

    $(this).empty(); // remove old content

    $.each(objectsSplit, function(index, value) {
        $('.wrapper > .objects').append("<div>" + value + "</div>");
    });

});
```

I want to wrap every "object" into a div and remove the ",".

What I want:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">
    <div>House</div>
    <div>Cat</div>
    <div>Dog<div>
    <div>Car</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">
    <div>House</div>
    <div>Cat</div>
    <div>Car</div>
  </div>
</div>
// and so on ...
```

With my script I can store them all in an array, but the `"$.each(objectsSplit, function(index, value) ...`" part doesn`t work - the script crashes. Whats my fail?

Comment: `the script crashes` and what is the error message?

Comment: What do you mean with "the script crashes"? The whole browser somehow gets too busy? The problem could be that you're adding to the collection that you're reading from, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, it starts an endless loop, I think - but @palaѕн solution looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening because you are trying to append the new divs to each `$('.wrapper > .objects')`, inside of the current `objects` you are looping over. You can fix it by caching the current `$(this)` like:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

and then using this jquery object for append like:

```
$this.append("<div>" + value + "</div>");
```

Instead of doing:

```
$('.wrapper > .objects').append("<div>" + value + "</div>");
```

DEMO:

```js
$('.wrapper > .objects').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var objects = $this.text();
    var objectsSplit = objects.split(',').map(s => s.trim());
    $this.empty(); // remove old content
    $.each(objectsSplit, function(index, value) {
        $this.append("<div>" + value + "</div>");
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper > .objects { border:2px solid green; margin: 5px; padding:5px 10px;}
.wrapper > .objects > div { background-color:#EEE;margin-bottom: 5px; padding:4px 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">House, Cat, Dog, Car</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">House, Cat, Car</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">Cat, Dog</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting way to store "this" - I will try it - one moment ...

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your current element and append to it as bellow:

```js
$('.wrapper > .objects').each(function() {
  const currentEl = this
  var objects = $(this).text();
  var objectsSplit = objects.split(',');

  // console.log(objectsSplit);

  $(this).empty(); // remove old content

  $.each(objectsSplit, function(index, value) {
      $(currentEl).append("<div>" + value + "</div>");
  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">House, Cat, Dog, Car</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">House, Cat, Car</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="objects">Cat, Dog</div>
</div>
```